# ReactJS: How to add a style to children if all children are functional components?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have a project where I want to apply a certain style to. I tried the method shown below (which does **not** work for functional components):

```js
const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  const style = { /* ... */ }

  const clones = React.Children.map(children, child => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, { style: style });
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {clones}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

During my search I found that this method seems to only work for class components and not functional ones. This is a problem for me as the whole project uses only functional components.

I also found that people circumvented this issue by adding a style prop to their child components like so (In my case, I **cannot** add a `style` prop to any of the child components):

```js
const Child = ({ style }) => {
  return (
    <div style={style}>
      hello world
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

This method works only if you can edit the child components to have props, but I plan to use this module in other projects where I cannot edit the child components. So this solution is, unfortunately, not feasible.

Edit: More clarification added to paragraphs 3 and 4.

Comment: You want to edit the child component's style using the style you make from the parent component?

Comment: @Dylan Yes. The parent component needs the children to have certain style properties, and editing the children to have a style prop is not feasible.

In other words, I have access to the parent and not the children.

Comment: if you can't send a style to your child component, and you can't add a static style to it, how would your child component know what style it will going to have?

Comment: It would be helpful to know specifically what styling you're talking about. Perhaps, what you need is just to map over the children and wrap each of them with a div with the specified style property. Hard to say without knowing the nature of the styling and the structure of children.

Comment: @Dylan the above method worked for class components without having to add a style prop to the children. I'm asking if it's possible to do the same for functional components.

Comment: @Ports I didn't think of that. That could be useful, so I'll look into it, and if it solves my problem I'll make an edit/answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, mapping over the children and wrapping each of them with a div element with a specified style would be sufficient. As I wrote in the comment to the OP, it all depends on the nature of the styling modifications needed and the structure of the children:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My App</h1>
      <Parent>
        <ChildComponent />
        <ChildComponent />
      </Parent>
    </div>
  );
};

const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  const style = { color: "blue" };

  const clones = React.Children.map(children, (child) =>
   <div style={style}>{child}</div>
  );

  return <div>{clones}</div>;
};

const ChildComponent = () => {
  return <h2>this is a child component</h2>;
};
export default App;
```

Comment: This might be the way to go, however, I cant stop thinking about how stupid react is in many cases compared to Vue...

Answer (score -1):

You can see the change when you pass the child to the parent.

[see result](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-mestorf-4pcqh?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
return (
<div className="App">
  <Parent>
    <Child />
  </Parent>
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm saying this method doesn't work for me because I **cannot** add the style prop to the child elements.

Answer (score -2):

You can just import the child component to the parent component and pass the style props

Try this

```js
import Child from 'path-to-child-file'

const Parent = ({ }) => {
  const style = { /* ... */ }

  return (
    <div>
      <Child style={style} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Parent;
```

you don't need to edit your child component

Comment: This implies that my child component has a `style` prop, which it doesn't. And I can't add a `style` prop to it. Additionally this passes the style to only one child, I want to pass it to arbitrarily many children.